# Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'angular-material' imported by the module 'MyMaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep have this error

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MatPaginator' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

this is my material module

```
import { NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource,MatButtonModule, 
MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MatButtonModule,MatTableModule,
              MatPaginator, MatSort, 
              MatTableDataSource],
    exports: [MatButtonModule,MatTableModule,MatPaginator, MatSort, 
             MatTableDataSource],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

and this is my app.module

```
...
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...

  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and also this is my view

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
   <div class="example-header">
     <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" 
    placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

```
<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> email </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Color Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> phone </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="company">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> company </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

i took it from [angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) how can i fix it ?

Comment: I would import `MatPaginatorModule`

Comment: i've imported it and still that error appear

Comment: Did you remove `MatPaginator` from `imports`?

Comment: yes ill update the post

Comment: i took it from the angular material doc

Comment: See here https://plnkr.co/edit/CRUeXNF5sxolSbiooyEn?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CRUeXNF5sxolSbiooyEn?p=preview its not working "Loading Material Docs example... "  ive wait it for long time

Comment: I see. I updated https://plnkr.co/edit/CRUeXNF5sxolSbiooyEn?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I imported the `MatPaginatorModule` inside my `@NgModule` into the imports array.
It solved my problem. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 6):

You are importing **MatPaginator** module, insted of importing **MatPaginator** please import **MatPaginatorModule** module. Have the same issue this one work for me.

Like:

```
// material.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatTableModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatTableModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import MatPaginator Module but you're importing MatPaginator, change it in your MaterialModule and you're done.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

const MaterialModules = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatPaginatorModule
]

These are the modules, I have impoted and exported modules from material but not individual components or buttons etc.. (most generalized)

I beleive MatPaginatorModule is the one which you need to import and it will provide all required directives or components for your case